# Carregar campo DataTime

Tags: php

Estou tentando carregar um campo `data` vindo do banco de dados, tentei setar o valor no `atributo value` porem não tive sucesso qual a melhor pratica para isto ?

```
<input value="<?php echo @$linha[DAT_EHORA_EVENT];?>" id="DAT_EHORA_EVENT" name="DAT_EHORA_EVENT" type="datetime-local" placeholder="" class="input-large">
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_datetime-local_defaultvalue.asp

Comment: aqui estão todos os atributos para esse tipo de input http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_datetime-local.asp

Comment: Não conseguir achar nada que sane minha duvida.

Comment: Ele vem em branco? ou não vem formatada a data?

Comment: Ele vem em branco. @rray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você está esquecendo de envolver o nome do campo com ASPAS (no seu caso, aspas simples)

```
<input value="<?php echo @$linha['DAT_EHORA_EVENT'];?>" id="DAT_EHORA_EVENT" name="DAT_EHORA_EVENT" type="datetime-local" placeholder="" class="input-large">
```